# Can $f''(x)$ exist if $f'(x)$ is undefined?

Tags: derivatives

For example, the piecewise function

$
f(x) = 
\begin{cases} 
\sqrt{1 - (x + 1)^2} &-2 \leq x \leq 0 \\ 
-\sqrt{1 - (x - 1)^2} &0 \leq x \leq 2
\end{cases}
$

will, at $f(0)$, give $f'(0) = $ undefined (vertical tangent).  Once deriving I can prove this algebraically, there is a zero in the denominator.  It looked like an inflection point, so I wondered if $f''(x)$ would equal zero or undefined.  After taking the (painstakingly ugly) second derivative, I ran into another zero in the denominator error, so $f''(0)$ is also undefined.  Is this a general rule that if $f'(x)$ is undefined $f''(x)$ will also be undefined?

Thanks :)

Comment: From the limit definition of the derivative, no.

Comment: @copper.hat ...  Your answer "No" is for the title, or the question in the body?  They have opposite answers.

Comment: @GEdgar: It was an answer to the title question, but have removed my comment since it wasn't very helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remember the definition of the derivative:
$$
f'(x) = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x+h)  - f(x)}{h}.
$$
For this definition to make any sense, $f(x)$ must be defined. In your example, since $f'(0)$ is undefined, neither is $f''(0)$.

Answer (score 0):

mathematician has extended the concept of derivatives into left and right derivatives to deal the case you are facing. As long %x =0$ is negligible for you, you can replace it with left and right derivatives at that point.

See Wiki:
[Left and Right derivatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left_and_right_derivative)

Answer (score 0):

Think of this with the fact that

> Differentiable implies continuous

That is, if $g$ is differentiable, then $g$ is continuous. Apply this to $g=f'$.

> If $f'$ is differentiable at $x$, that is $f''(x)$ exists, then $f'$ is continuous at $x$. This implies $f'(x)$ exists.